# how to match statement that combine word,/,digits like /dev/home/hello-world

Tags: regex

i want to match following statement in regex:

```
/
/dev/shm
/var/lib/snap/hello-world/27
```

any idea?
and this is my last try:

```
\/((\w+)|(\/\w+-\w+))+
```

but it seems that, dash-statements treat like a seperate part.

Comment: @Jan : Post updated!

Comment: You can use `^\/(?:[^/]*\/)*.*$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex using a negated character class:

```
^\/(?:[^/]*\/)*.*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOoXJ2/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `\/`: Match literal `/`
- `(?:[^/]*\/)*`: Match 0 or more groups of non-slash strings followed by a `/`
- .*`: Match anything after last`/`
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

If you are a positive person and don't want to use negative classes (as proposed by @anubhava), you can check this fully positive regex:

```
^(?:(?:\/)|(?:\/\w+)|(?:\/\w+-\w+))+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEAgg7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone. all your answers works. but i find a simple approach:

```
(\/([\w\d\-\/])*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEAgg7/1/)